# Change the color of cubes in three.js after button click

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to change the color of cubes after clicking on the button. I tried couple of suggested answers from the various posts, but so far no luck. As suggested I added the `geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;` and other setting to true. After that I iterate thought the faces like this:

```
function testFXN() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
        geometry.faces[i].color.setRGB(1,1,1);
    }

    defaultMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff, 
        shading: THREE.FlatShading, 
        vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors
    }); 
}
```

I am playing around with this example from three.js

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu

Color of the cubes remained unchanged. Any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: set color to material `material.color.setHex(0xffffff );`